# What to do if I have another question regarding the same project as previous question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

SCENARIO: I have a project named "Alphabet", problem A arises; I post question A and found a solution(no upvotes, no downvotes, feedback provided only by one user), but then problem B arises. Should I

- Post question B as a new question referencing question A
- Modify/Edit A in such a way that it becomes B
- Post B as an entirely new question without any reference to A

Comment: So, to clarify, the feedback posted on question A was only a comment? Or did the user on question A post the solution? (Not that it changes the answer much, but for clarity sake.)

Comment: Sorry went out for lunch, the feedback posted was an answer @Kendra

Comment: It's not too big a deal- As I said, it really doesn't change the answer much. :) In the end, I just opted to cover as many possible situations as I could think of in my answer here.

Comment: Be sure to upvote the answer to question A if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to post question B as a separate question. Whether you reference A or not depends.

Is question B related to the solution to question A? As in, is the solution to question A what caused the problem in question B? Then it's suggested to link to A as a background. *However,* make sure question B stands without question A. Include the code that is causing the problem and the description of what you're trying to do.

Is question B only related to question A in that by solving question A you were able to run your code further and found question B? Then no reference to question A is needed.

Regardless of whether you received an answer to A, it's frowned upon to change a question into a completely different question. However, it's more frowned upon if there are already answers to the question. That's what we call a ["chameleon question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), and it makes the original answers invalid. That serves the purpose of making the original answerer look bad.

Now if question B is in all actuality a *clarification* of question A, as in you figured out something with question A via the feedback provided you and need to clarify something that may help in getting an answer to question A, without making the question off-topic for Stack Overflow, *then* it's alright to edit question A into question B.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. Now I know how to proceed.