# Rejected rollback edit suggestion

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

A user received an answer to [their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617742/java-practice-array-code-not-compiling-what-is-my-error) via the comments, and then made edits to their post to reflect a new question. I submitted a suggestion to revert the edit and added a comment to the user.

However, [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10785151) was rejected on grounds that:

> [The] edit deviates from the original intent of the post.

Though the entire point of the edit was to return the post to its original intent. Made evident by the OP's un-edited title.

I certainly wasn't unclear in *my* intent. Here is my edit comment:

> Rollback suggested, OP has edited his post to be an entirely new question. Have advised OP to create a new post.

I am under the assumption this edit failed because few chose to read the comment and instead saw only the drastic post change. Should I have raised a flag to get the post rolled back, or simply requested the change in a chatroom?

We put a lot of stress on maintaining accurate and helpful comment edits, but I wonder how often they're actually read.

The post has since been put on hold, but I imagine it should still be rolled back (**edit:** disregard, the post will be deleted in 9 days anyway).

Comment: Until you have 2k rep, you shouldn't really be doing rollbacks. I would suggest leaving a comment, and possibly enlisting the help of others in [chat].

Comment: I would agree if it was someone below 1k like myself, but for a user who is almost 2k, suggesting the rollback and commenting seems like a fair course of action @TinyGiant

Comment: @JustDoIt 1k is the same as 500 where edits are concerned. Once you have 2k your edits are no longer reviewed in the queue.

Comment: I was implying that I disagree with your *Until you have 2k rep, you shouldn't really be doing rollbacks* statement, he's pretty close to it as is, suggesting a rollback is okay for me, it's still a suggestion. @TinyGiant

Comment: @CubeJockey 2k+ users can see suggested edits on posts and approve them if necessary.

Comment: @JustDoIt It was a massive change to the code, of course it is going to be rejected. There is a reason there is no rollback link when you have less than 2k, because you shouldn't be rolling back edits. If you think an edit should be rolled back, and have less than 2k  you should bring it to the attention of users who can do a rollback. 1974 rep is not 2000.

Comment: To elaborate on @TinyGiant 's comment, both 2k reviewers and post owner get the "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit" options.  These options immediately resolve the suggestion and then apply further edits to the post.

Comment: that just means reviewers don't read the reasoning behind the suggestion @TinyGiant which makes it not cube's fault

Comment: To be fair, a suggestion with a clear comment *is* bringing it to the attention of users who can do a rollback. Any >2k rep user could "improve and edit" the suggestion to auto-approve

Comment: @JustDoIt It doesn't matter what the reasoning was, it was a massive change to the code that *did* deviate from the original intent of the author. The edit was rolling back an edit *made by the OP*.

Comment: @TinyGiant We are straying close to pendantry with defining "author's original intent." Should the initial post question remain the intent of the author/post and its edits?

Comment: Deviating from the intent of the author is deviating from the intent of the author. If you're suggesting an edit that rolls back an edit made by the author of the post, then you are deviating from the author's intent.

Comment: @TinyGiant original intent of the author was already changed by himself, a new post should've been done, not an edit. [relevant?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310494/5067286)

Comment: Google "turd polishing".

Comment: @JustDoIt the author cannot deviate from his own intent, he is the one who determines his own intent. He can incorrectly edit his own post to invalidate answers, which should be rolled back by someone with greater than 2000 rep.

Comment: It's not worth it. It is closed and downvoted, it will be deleted 9 days after the closure date automatically.

Comment: @TinyGiant question was posted 2hrs ago, comment suggestion was posted also 2 hours ago, edit suggestion was rejected 1hr ago, which seems like a fair amount of time for a +2k rep user to notice

Comment: @JustDoIt It isn't answered, so the edit doesn't invalidate existing answers. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @TinyGiant The post was answered in the comments, so then OP made those code changes and edited the post to be a new question. But you're correct, no *answers* were submitted.

Comment: That some reviewers don't even bother to read the edit summary section, which is key when reviewing suggested edits, how will you know editors thoughts if not for the edit summary? @TinyGiant

Comment: Why would you say they didn't read it? The fact even if they did read it, which they probably did, it does not matter. The edit massively changed the code and deviated from the author's intent. The edit was rejected correctly. @JustDoIt

Comment: @CubeJockey yep.  I think that's the key point.  Comments aren't answers and shouldn't be treated as such.

Comment: The OP edited their question into something that does not produce an error, we have a close reason for that. If the edit had invalidated existing answers, it would have warranted a rollback from a 2k+ user.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yup, I believe that'll be the deciding factor here!

Comment: In 2 more rep this won't be a problem!

Comment: @Tas while you may be right, if I had the correct amount of rep to auto-edit, my action would have still been a problem and likely caused a similar discussion. So, fortunately the suggestion went under review and gave us a lesson to learn.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't see your point with regards to the 2k rep limit. Are you suggesting that if you have 2k rep, it's okay to make edits that deviate from the author's intent? Because if you're not, I see no reason whatsoever that sub-2k users shouldn't be able to submit these types of edits. All that matters is whether it's a good edit or not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A few notes first:

- A question is not "answered" in comments. If someone wanted to answer that question, they should've posted **an answer**. I would default to assuming that the lack of answers was an indication that the folks commenting wished to help the asker improve his question, *not* freeze it in time and prevent alterations.
- There is no built-in facility for "suggesting" a rollback. Authors and [privileged users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) have this option, but there's no equivalent for low-rep editors; you can only suggest an edit which is equivalent to a previous version of the post - this *can* be functionally the same as a rollback, but is tracked differently internally and of course *presented to reviewers* as a normal edit. Generally, it takes more effort for a privileged user to review an edit than to simply roll back the post himself, so supporting this is kind of a waste of time.
- The first goal of any edit should be to make the post as good as you can possibly make it. There are other guidelines, helpfully listed in the sidebar of the editing page, but under no circumstances should you make a post *worse* just for the heck of it. If you can't improve it, *don't edit.*

Now... I trust that you had the best of intentions here. But all you did was restore the post to a state that *had already gotten it closed*. It wasn't answered, and there certainly wasn't anything in the comments worth keeping for posterity; you'd have been better off just leaving it to be deleted than trying to roll it back.

If you *were* determined to edit, you could've tried to make the new question into something clear and useful - something worth reopening. You might've edited the title and added a bit of detail on what was going wrong, for instance. From the look of things, that would've still been futile in this case since it would've just been a duplicate of a previous question... But as a general principle, if you're editing a closed question you should aim for a result that's worth reopening; otherwise you're just re-arranging deck chairs on The Titanic.

Comment: Yup, that is clear now. Good intentions aside, I wasn't paying attention. The question being put on hold and a lack of actual answers invalidated any possible motivation for rollbacks. Wasted time all around! I can see why <2k users aren't allowed rollback-functionality.